# User flair is getting overlapped by other various elements on the page

Tags: bug, design

If an editor has enough rep and badges, the badges and their count starts getting behind OP's flair rectangle:

[image]

This problem can be seen in this post:

[Do in-universe characters look down on Hufflepuff?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105975/do-in-universe-characters-look-down-on-hufflepuff)

At the second glance OP's flair can get overlapped by other elements like the right widget column:

[image]

[image]

Comment: actually I think the whole site is affected and all flairs are overlapping a bit :(

Comment: Wow, my flair is getting slightly overlapped - I feel important now!